# PHP SQL query to sum up all the completed tasks of the day

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to develop a basic PHP code which will connect to the database, select the table "a" and check all the entries for the last 24 hours. If the value "b" of the entries is > 3 the query will understand them as completed, summarize them and echo the number of the completed ones.

This is what i have so far:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("details hidden for security"); 
if (mysql_connect_errno($con)) { 
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error(); 
 } 
$now = time();
$onedayago = $now - (24*60*60);
$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM 'a' WHERE 'b' = 3 AND 'b' >= $onedayago AND 'b' <= $now");
if($result === FALSE) 
{
die(mysql_error());
}
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
$count = $data['total']; 
}
 echo $count;
?>
```

Comment: remove the single quotes around the column names as they are identifiers not string literals. `SELECT * FROM a WHERE b = 3 AND b >= $onedayago AND b <= $now`

Comment: `mysql` is depreciated try to use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: Also you cannot mix `mysql` and `mysqli`. You are connecting using `mysql` and executing query using `mysqli` this wont work.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're using `mysql_connect()` to connect to the database, but after that you're using `mysqli_query()` to execute the query. Do not mix these.

Secondly, you do not need single quotes around the identifiers. It should be:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE b = 3 AND b >= $onedayago AND b <= $now
```

Also, `mysql()` is officially deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and it's recommended to switch to `mysqli()` or `PDO`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers but applying those changes i just get a white screen. Thanks!